# Laravel 5.2 Adding a terms and condition in register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add a terms and condition in the validation form of my register but it is not working. Can some one help me with this.

View

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('terms') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="terms" value="{{ old('terms') }}" /> Agree with the terms and conditions
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    @if ($errors->has('terms'))
     <span class="help-block">
       <strong>{{ $errors->first('terms') }}</strong>
     </span>
    @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

AuthController

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'company' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'telephone' => 'required|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
            'terms' => 'required'
          ]);

    }
```

Comment: Even when all the forms was filled up and the checkbox is already checked.  Its not registering. in the checkbox said the terms required.

Comment: No erros. it stays in the registration form and there's this "The terms field is required" even if it is already checked

Comment: `print_r($data)` and check terms value is exist or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="terms" value="{{ old('terms') }}" /> Agree with the terms and conditions
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="terms" value="1" /> Agree with the terms and conditions
```

because we maintain the old value for textbox, textarea etc in case if the entered old value do not pass the validation, but in your case checkbox require a static value i.e. 1 or any value. 
If it is not selected than show the error, but its value remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

Checkbox validations are harder because they are not sent in request unchecked. Laravel has the **accepted** validation rule for your case (the value of the checkbox needs to be *yes*, *on*, *true* or *1*. Also, to have the old input back on error, just use:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="true" {{ !old('terms') ?: 'checked' }}>
```

Comment: Plus one for a better explanation :)